# How can I remove unnecessary new lines?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a file on AIX.
I would like to remove the unnecessary new lines, but at the same time give a new line after the eighth character ^

```
cat file

    TEST1^2017-11-16^D^N^23:50^123^^^
    TEST1^2017-11-17^D^N^23:50^^123^ALL^
    TEST1^2017-11-18^D^N^23:50^^^12345
    ,123456
    ,12
    ,1234
    ,12345678
    ,1
    ,123
    ,12345
    ,12345
    ,12345
    ,123
    ,1234567890
    ,1234
    ,1234
    ,1234567
    ,1234567^
    TEST2^2017-11-16^D^N^23:50^^^^
    TEST2^2017-11-17^D^N^23:50^^^^
    TEST2^2017-11-18^D^N^23:50^^^^
    TEST3^2017-11-23^D^N^23:50^^^^
```

And I need this:

```
TEST1^2017-11-16^D^N^23:50^123^^^
TEST1^2017-11-17^D^N^23:50^^123^ALL^
TEST1^2017-11-18^D^N^23:50^^^12345,123456,12,1234,12345678,1,123,12345,12345,12345,123,1234567890,1234,1234,1234567,1234567^
TEST2^2017-11-16^D^N^23:50^^^^
TEST2^2017-11-17^D^N^23:50^^^^
TEST2^2017-11-18^D^N^23:50^^^^
TEST3^2017-11-23^D^N^23:50^^^^
```

please help

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Looks like you also need to remove the indentation at the beginning of each line. Or was that a copying error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not accounting for possible incorrect leading whitespace in the sample input. If there are 8 `^`, there should be 9 fields per record.

```
awk -F'^' '{
    # keep concatenating lines while there are fewer than 9 fields
    while (NF < 9) {getline next_line; $0 = $0 next_line}
    print
}' file
```

```
    TEST1^2017-11-16^D^N^23:50^123^^^
    TEST1^2017-11-17^D^N^23:50^^123^ALL^
    TEST1^2017-11-18^D^N^23:50^^^12345    ,123456    ,12    ,1234    ,12345678    ,1    ,123    ,12345    ,12345    ,12345    ,123    ,1234567890    ,1234    ,1234    ,1234567    ,1234567^
    TEST2^2017-11-16^D^N^23:50^^^^
    TEST2^2017-11-17^D^N^23:50^^^^
    TEST2^2017-11-18^D^N^23:50^^^^
    TEST3^2017-11-23^D^N^23:50^^^^
```

Comment: Yeah, this makes me want to claw my eyes out a lot less than my solution.  I need to learn awk.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

I think you just need this

```
$ awk -v RS= '{print gensub("([^^])\n","\1","g")}' file

TEST1^2017-11-16^D^N^23:50^123^^^
TEST1^2017-11-17^D^N^23:50^^123^ALL^
TEST1^2017-11-18^D^N^23:50^^^1234,12345,1,123,1234567,,12,1234,1234,1234,12,123456789,123,123,123456,1234567^
TEST2^2017-11-16^D^N^23:50^^^^
TEST2^2017-11-17^D^N^23:50^^^^
TEST2^2017-11-18^D^N^23:50^^^^
TEST3^2017-11-23^D^N^23:50^^^^
```

if my assumption is not correct and line breaks can happen anywhere, this is probably the simplest solution

```
$ <file tr -d '\n' | sed -E 's/([^^]*\^){8}/&\n/g'
```

Comment: How does this know to wait for the 8th ^ ?

Comment: it doesn't.  Based on your structure the incorrect line-breaks happen within a field.

Comment: ah, got it.  not mine, btw.  I'm the perl answer :)

Answer (score -3):

This is a grotesque answer, but it's an answer:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\n//g' input_file
```

will get rid of all your newlines

```
perl -pi -e 's/((.*?\^){8})/$1\n/g' input_file
```

Will add a newline for every 8th ^.

I suspect an awk solution is going to be *way* cleaner, and even my perl solution is ridiculous, but this is something.